# Javascript Counterup 2 - apply code on all elements

Tags: javascript

I found this javascript code that runs Counterup 2 JS plugin [(Codepen)](https://codepen.io/bfintal/pen/zYzOGpZ) on my website:

```
const counterUp = window.counterUp.default

const callback = entries => {
    entries.forEach( entry => {
        const el = entry.target
        if ( entry.isIntersecting && ! el.classList.contains( 'is-visible' ) ) {
            counterUp( el, {
                duration: 2000,
                delay: 16,
            } )
            el.classList.add( 'is-visible' )
        }
    } )
}

const IO = new IntersectionObserver( callback, { threshold: 1 } )

const el = document.querySelector( '.info-bubble .title .number' )
IO.observe( el )
```

But it's working only for 1 element. I have 2 elements with same class `.number`. But only one element is counting up when I scroll down. How to apply this code on all elements with same class? I tried to use `document.querySelectorAll()` method but with no any result.

Comment: Because `querySelector` returns only the first element it finds - you'll need to use `querySelectorAll` to get all of them returned. And then you will need to loop over those and call `IO.observe` for each one individually, because that method only take a single element as parameter, not a list of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can modify your code to loop through all the elements returned by document.querySelectorAll('.number') and observe each of them with the IntersectionObserver like so:

```
const counterUp = window.counterUp.default;

const callback = entries => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        const el = entry.target;
        if (entry.isIntersecting && !el.classList.contains('is-visible')) {
            counterUp(el, {
                duration: 2000,
                delay: 16,
            });
            el.classList.add('is-visible');
        }
    });
};

const IO = new IntersectionObserver(callback, { threshold: 1 });

// Get all elements with the class '.number'
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.number');

// Observe each element
elements.forEach(el => {
    IO.observe(el);
});
```